# Highcharts' getExtremes function can't return correct dataMax

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using one highchart to control another one. After setting the chart.evetns.selection, chart.yAxis.getExtremes can't return correct dataMax if I zoom a tiny region. However, if I click once again, then it return the correct one. Any suggestion to avoid this? here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tianhuidong/Jhupu/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                selection: function (event) {
                    m1 = event.xAxis[0].min
                    m2 = event.xAxis[0].max
                    var chart1 = $('#container1').highcharts()
                    var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts()
                    chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(m1, m2);
                    chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(m1, m2);
                },
                click: function (event) {
                    var chart1 = $('#container1').highcharts()
                    var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts()
                    xx = chart1.xAxis[0].getExtremes()
                    yy = chart1.yAxis[0].getExtremes()
                    alert(yy.min)
                    alert(yy.dataMax)
                    alert(yy.userMax)
                    alert(Object.keys(yy))
                    chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xx.dataMin, xx.dataMax);
                    chart1.yAxis[0].setExtremes(yy.dataMin, yy.dataMax);
                    chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xx.dataMin, xx.dataMax);
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },


        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        var chart1 = $('#container1').highcharts()
                        var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts()
                        //alert(Object.keys(chart1.series[0]))
                        chart2.series[0].hide()
                        //chart2.showResetZoom()
                        //alert(Object.keys(chart.resetZoomButton))



                    }
                }
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 186.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 186.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 116.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 186.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set a minRange parameter ? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange

Comment: No, as you can see from the code. Does minRange have default value? Now I figured out by calculating the maximum of series[i].yData.